# Manipulating the browser chrome in a web extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to develop a small extension to hide the browser chrome for a use case. It seems that the new way to develop addons is to use the web extension api. With the old api it seems to be possible to manipulate the chrome. E.g. in the webdeveloper console (with some config flags) I was able to run this code:

```
document.getElementById('toolbar-menubar').style.display = 'none';
```

However it seems to be impossible with the web extension api. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is `Browser Chrome`?

Comment: Things like the tab bar, menu bar, navigation, search etc which is part of the browser, but not part of the website which is displayed.

Comment: Just as reference how to enable that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox